# window.location is not working in chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, redirect, window.location

i have used window.location on click of button. I tried giving both absolute and relative path. Still it is not working. No error in console log.
It works only in Safari browser

Comment: Are u trying redirect ?

Comment: can you provide your source code ?

Answer (score 0):

window.location may or may not be read only.

Try using window.location.assign("www.example.com")

see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location

Answer (score -1):

The most common use of `window.location` is to make the browser load a new page. A common error is to assign the URL to the `window.location` object instead of it's property `href`. So, the correct way to do it is:

```
window.location.href = 'https://www.google.com/';
```